Pandas read_sql with Parameters Gives `TypeError: dict is not a sequence` for PostgreSQL Database
I am trying to use parameters for SQL queries with Pandas:
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql:///mydb')
conn = engine.connect()
sql = '''
SELECT id, name, age FROM person WHERE name=%{name}s
'''

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params={'name': 'John Doe'})
print(df)

From how I understand the Pandas documentation this should work.  But it throws a 'Type Error: dict is not a sequence'.
The solution is to wrap the SQL in text() from SQLAlchemy and use a different placeholder syntax:
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text

engine = create_engine('postgresql:///mydb')
conn = engine.connect()
sql = '''
SELECT id, name, age FROM person WHERE name=:name
'''

df = pd.read_sql(text(sql), conn, params={'name': 'John Doe'})
print(df)

I am fine using text() because it makes the code also independent of the backend.  But what is wrong with the first approach? IMHO, it exactly follows the docs.

I have found that you can pass the engine directly to read_sql's 'con' argument (e.g. df = pd.read_sql(text(sql), con = engine, params={'name': 'John Doe'}) ). This is made more clear within the documentation for to_sql (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable//reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), but it works just as well within read_sql also.

It is expecting parenthesis not curly brackets:
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql:///mydb')
conn = engine.connect()
sql = '''
SELECT id, name, age FROM person WHERE name=%(name)s
'''

df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn, params={'name': 'John Doe'})
print(df)


OMG, how stupid of me! :)
